# Activity order from notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

I have a question regarding Android Notification and activity order.

I have following scenario:

I have Activity_Main as my first activity, which performs some task. When BACK button is pressed It generates notification. Activity_Main has following calls (`onKeyDown()`, `OnPause()`, `OnStop()`, `OnDestroy()`). When user clicks the notification icon Activity_Main is started and call sequence is (`OnCreate()`, `OnResume()`). Which is fine.

Now Activity_Main contains button which starts Activity_Second using `StartActivityForResult()` api and also generates notification of task progress, function calls are (`onSaveInstance()`, `OnPause()`, `OnStop()`). If user presses back button on Activity_Second by `setResult(result)`, everything works fine. But if the user selects the Notification icon (activity_seconds is visible) then new instance on Activity_main (`onCreate()`, `OnResume()`) started. What i want is Activity_Second should close it and (`onResume()` of Activity_Main) should be called. Right now Activity_Main(2nd instance), Activity_second, Activity_Main(1st instance) is on activity stack.

I have following flags set while generating notification.

```
notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
```

What is other way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ vineet, it didnt help.

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this,Activity_Main.class);
```

and

```
<activity ....android:launchMode="singleTask" >
```

togather helped me to solve this...
[from this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326622/starting-activity-through-notification-avoiding-duplicate-activities)

Answer (score 1):

try after adding these flags to your intent:

```
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_LAUNCHED_FROM_HISTORY);
notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```