# Run Activity in background without UI

Tags: android-service, android, android-gesture

In my application, I want to use stealth mode so that the service which is containing some activities in it will be running in the background. But at the same time on certain guesture or some combination of keys I need to start another activity which will be having some UI in it.Is this possible?? If so please let me know I have tried using longpress on screen but it needs an activity running, in order to start another activity,whereas when I tried to override the home button or menu button it again needs an activity running in the front to enable long press. 
       Is there a way wherein I can make use of guesture listener through service or without making use of activity.
       Please suggest me a good solution for this problem because I have been searching a lot for the same.

Answer (score 1):

The SDK does not allow this for security reasons, as a malicious app could intercept a user's touch events and absorb them, rendering any other feature of the device useless.

You could however have your app listen for shake events and launch your activity upon the user shaking the device from a Service.

Comment: Raghav I tried shake events also but what I am targeting in shake is a shake combination like left-left-right-right or as many combinations of left right,can you suggest a solution for this,if I am able to do this then also my application will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I think [Android notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) suit well for your needs. You can "inject" your service's icon into Android screen, and react to interactions with user. You may find answers on SO, which demonstrate how to launch an activity from a notification. Here is [one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326622/starting-activity-through-notification-avoiding-duplicate-activities).

Comment: Thanks a lot stan I will try your suggestion, but can you tell me if we can use long press on the home screen to start an app without disturbing other applicaions.

Comment: @Max I don't think you can't do exactly this. But there exist [app widgets](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html), which can be added to home screen.